# Reverse engineering - Flash app

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript-2

I have that code:

```
private function handleFlashVarsXmlLoaded(event:Event) : void
    {
        var secondsplit:String = null;
        var item:Array = null;
        var string:* = XML(String(event.target.data)); 
        var notsplited:* = string.vars_CDATA;  //what is .vars_CDATA?
        var splitted:* = notsplitted.split("&");
        var datacontainer:Object = {}; 
        var index:Number = 0;

        item = secondsplit.split("="); 
        datacontainer[item[0]] = item[1];

        this.parseFlashVars(datacontainer); // go next
        return;
    }
```

That function is loaded when URLLoader is loaded.
I think that this function parse a XML file to string(fe. `param1=arg1&param2=arg2`), then split it by "&" and then by "=" and add data to datacontainer by

```
datacontainer["param1"] = "arg1"
```

But how should the XML file look like and what is string.**vars_CDATA**

Comment: do you have a sample of the data which was loaded? vars_CDATA will be a node in the xml. best practices asside, this code is very easy to follow... who names a variable 'string' anyway??

Answer (score 0):

I think, vars_CDATA is just a name of XML field, becourse variable named "string" is contains whole XML. So var "notsplited" contains a String-typed data of this field (I think so, becourse of the line "var splitted:* = notsplitted.split("&");", which splits String to Array).